# Send user location coordinates to SMS.app as an googleMaps-link

Tags: iphone, google-maps, sms, mapkit, messageui

I wanna send my location coordinates as a Google Maps link (http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f) as an SMS but i just can't get it to work... How should I do so that the GoogleMaps-link varies to my location??

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

        controller.body = @"This is my location http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f";

    NSString *googleMaps = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", location.latitude, location.longitude];

    controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
            controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];  
            }
    }
```

Any ideas? Would really appreciate an answer!!!!

Thanks you and happy holidays!

Comment: what's not working in this code?

Comment: nothing's happening with the link when I try send the link... I wanna make it change the GoogleMaps-link to my current location....

Comment: what is the output of the string you create?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldn't you have:

```
controller.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f", location.latitude, location.longitude];
```

you're hard coding the body and then creating an unrelated string which is probably properly formatted and never doing anything with it.

Comment: You need to get familiar with nsstring, you'll be using it all over the place learn it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude assuming location is a cllocation object.

Comment: It's a CLLocationCoordinate2D... so I cant put it as location.coordinate.longitude and location.coordinate.latitude !